# Logger does not work auto automatically when I use SQL Server

Tags: logging, log4net, aspnetboilerplate

I want to write log texts into SQL Server, when U use `Logger.Debug()` method, it works well.

But if the project throws some exception, it writes nothing into SQL Server.
But when I use the `log4net.config` that write logs to txt, it works well.

I do not know whether my `log4net.config` is wrong! Can you help me?

```
<appender name="AdoNetAppender_SQLServer" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <bufferSize value="1" />
    <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/> 
    <connectionString value="Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=myproject; User ID=sa; Password=123456;" />
    <commandText value="INSERT INTO dbo.Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@thread" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_level" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%level" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logger" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
             <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@exception" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="2000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
    </parameter>
</appender>

<root>
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender_SQLServer" />
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect an ambient transaction exists, which the ADO database connection is enlisting with. When an exception occurs the ambient transaction is rolled back, which includes the log entries inserted into the database.

Try adding `Enlist=false` to your connection string in the appender config.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer ,but it does not work.when i use Logger.Error(),it works well,so,i think it need some special setting for ABP